# the right command to select the number of products of every client that had a purchase in the last month

Tags: oracle

oracle question i've go this table

COM (Clientnumber,Productnumber,DateofPurchase ) ; 
i want to know how to compare the dates using sysdate and the date of purchase to know which one happened last month

Comment: `sysdate` is an [tag:oracle] pseudocolumn, but the question is tagged with [tag:mysql]. Which one is it?

Comment: my bad , i was studying both and got confused  its oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this one can solve your problem

```
SELECT * FROM COM
WHERE DateofPurchase between trunc((trunc(sysdate,'MM')-1),'MM')  and trunc(sysdate,'MM')-1

trunc((trunc(sysdate,'MM')-1),'MM') -->  last_month_fist_day
trunc(sysdate,'MM')-1               -->  last_month_last_day
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use PERIOD_DIFF

```
select Productnumber from COM where 
PERIOD_DIFF(EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM NOW()), EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM    DateofPurchase)) = 1
```